# Max Date with WHERE and HAVING clauses- Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a single transaction table with acc_nbr, tran_nbr, tran_amt, tran_dt, and tran_typ.

I need to find only acc_nbr where tran_typ = 'xx' and sum(tran_amt)<0 and show the most recent tran_dt.

I can find all accounts where the sum of the 'xx' tran_typ are less than zero, but I can't seem to get the date in there without adding all of the transactions that contain a negative tran_typ 'xx'.

What works so far:

```
    SEL acc_nbr, SUM(tran_amount) as error
    FROM DATABASE.TRAN_TBL

    WHERE tran_typ = 'xx' 
    GROUP BY acc_nbr
    HAVING sum(tran_amt)<0
```

How can I bring in the date of the latest transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best bet would be to find all accounts with negative sum in one set, latest date of transaction for each account in another set and inner join them both together on the same account.

You may want to try something like:

```
SEL sumtran.acc_nbr, sumtran.error, latest.latest_dt 
FROM 
  ( SEL acc_nbr, SUM(tran_amt) AS error
    FROM DATABASE.TRAN_TBL
    WHERE tran_typ = 'xx' 
    GROUP BY acc_nbr
    HAVING sum(tran_amt)<0 ) AS sumtran
INNER JOIN
  ( SEL acc_nbr, MAX(tran_dt) AS latest_dt
    FROM DATABASE.TRAN_TBL
    GROUP BY acc_nbr ) AS latest
ON sumtran.acc_nbr = latest.acc_nbr
```

Syntax for teradata might be slightly different but the overall idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure i understand the problem, but you should just be able to add a MAX(trans_dt) to the select and it will give you the more recent transaction date

```
SEL acc_nbr, SUM(tran_amount) as error, MAX(tran_dt) as most_recent_dt
FROM DATABASE.TRAN_TBL

WHERE tran_typ = 'xx' 
GROUP BY acc_nbr
HAVING sum(tran_amt)<0
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggest and I get accounts that do not meet the condition sum(tran_amt)<0. It looks like it returns the date of the greatest negative tran_amt for an acct, even if the total sum of those transactions is greater than zero. I hope that makes sense. It's almost like I need a max in the having clause?

Comment: The max(tran_date) is going to return the maximum value for the acc_nbr ...  That transaction itself may or may not be a negative value, but no rows in the result set will have a total positive sum (for the acc_nbr) because of your having clause.  What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I am trying to find accounts where the total amount of negative transactions of this type exceeds the sum of their total positive transactions of this type.  So, the customer can have many transactions, both positive and negative, but the sum of these transactions SHOULD always be positive. However, I have a bug in my system that sometimes posts an extra negative transaction which makes the sum of their transactions negative. So, I need to find all of the accts where trans total are negative but also need see last date they shopped (which may not be when they went neg).

Comment: The max date solution above gave me a date of a negative transaction of type 'xx', but there were other, newer transactions in the file for this acct (and the total sum of this acct was not negative). I think I need to first find all accts where sum <0, THEN apply max date to only those accts which sounds like a subquery of some kind. That's where I get lost :(

Comment: What i have posted above should do it then.  Adding the MAX(tran_dt) shouldnt affect the result set, just give you additional data.  Only thing i see wrong with it is that it should be SUM(tran_amt) in the select instead of SUM(tran_amount).  

do you get a different number of returned rows with the MAX(tran_dt) than without?

Comment: Yes. I have about 8,000 rows without the max dat and over a million with.

Comment: interesting, then Teradata's implementation of SQL must not be standard.  MAX should operate on the GROUP BY data, and the HAVING should happen after the group by as a filter.  Sounds like a sub query with joins is the way to go - the post below seems like a good answer

Comment: Yes, the sub query worked perfectly. Thank you for spending the time to help work through this!!

Comment: How do I respond to questions if not by chat? Do I select "Answer Your Question". We were discussing the issue at hand.